# Calculate risk between classes

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, inference, sas

I am doing some exercises about logistic regression with SAS and I need to calculate and interpret odds.

[image: SAS output]

For calculating the individual probabilities I use those formulas:

[image: rent vs own]

While later, the Professor, calculates odds for `rent` and `own` categories:

[image: odds for individual categories]

My question is, how is obtained the odd for `rent` of `0.3911` and the odd for `own` of `0.2610`? 
I don't understand from which calculations those numbers come from.

Moreover, in SAS I have class level information [image: class level information]

How to interpret it in this context and to use if for estimating odds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is:
$$logit(\pi) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{free} + \beta_2 x_{rent} $$

which becomes: 
$$ log{\pi \over{1-\pi}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{free} + \beta_2 x_{rent} $$
$$ log{~O_{y|x}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{free} + \beta_2 x_{rent} $$
Solving for $\beta_0$ ("own" coefficient) you get:
$$ \beta_0 = log{~ O_{y|x_{own}}}$$
$$ O_{y|x_{own}} = exp(\beta_0)$$
$$ O_{y|x_{own}} = exp(-1.0414) = 0.3529602$$

NB: This works because $x_{own}$ is chosen as the reference level for $x$ and its effect is in the model only when $x_{rent}=x_{free}=0$.

Similarly, solving for $\beta_2$ ("rent" coefficient) gives you:
$$ \beta_2 = (\beta_0 + \beta_2) - \beta_0  $$
$$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\beta_2 = log{~O_{y|x_{rent}}} - log{~O_{y|x_{own}}}  $$
$$\beta_2 = log{~O_{y|x_{rent}} \over ~O_{y|x_{own}} } $$
Therefore:
$$ {~O_{y|x_{rent}} = exp(\beta_2) \times ~O_{y|x_{own}} } $$
$${~O_{y|x_{rent}}} = 0.35296 \times exp(0.5987) = 0.6422995 $$

Comment: Thanks, what about the first log `0.6423`? How to get it?

Comment: I added the derivation to my answer.